# How can I script macOS to connect to WiFi with a VPN exactly the same to how iOS does the same?

Tags: macos, ios, wifi, software-recommendation, automation

I appreciate how iOS nicely shows a public WiFi onboarding / welcome screen (that makes you click "Accept", you-know-what) when connecting to public WiFi even though you've already connected to VPN

My macOS doesn't offer this unless I remember to disconnect from the VPN in advance.

It's very annoying that each time I try to connect to a public WiFi with my MacBook, I have to turn off VPN in advance, access " https://captive.apple.com/ " that invokes the welcome screen, and turn on the VPN again.

I'd like to figure out how the two OSes treat VPN and Public WiFi in different ways to write a script in macOS that mimics the behavior of iOS.

Specs:
iOS 16.3
macOS 13.1
VPN Mullvad 2022.5

Can this be scripted or has anyone made software to do this?

Comment: Are you happy with how macOS works when you manually disconnect the VPN? If so, the problem can be reduced to how to script your VPN to disconnect when the Mac sleeps / roams / leaves the prior WiFi network.

Answer (score -1):

One major differrence is that there is literally no way to block creepy local bonjour device visibility ( and potential direct connections) on iOS , where as on the less restrictive MacOS I can use my VPN apps firewall to compeltely block all local connections.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you explain the inability to block Bluetooth on iOS? My experience is the opposite and iOS offers far more privacy controls and gates to block app access to Bluetooth than macOS does.